# Get X coordinate from SDO_GEOMETRY point

Tags: sql, oracle, attributes, oracle-spatial

I have a SDO_GEOMETRY point:

```
 --yields SDO_GEOMETRY type, which contains an SDO_POINT
 select point from tbl 

  --yields a vertex_set_tye
 select SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(point) from tbl
```

How can I extract the X coordinate value using: `SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(point)`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can access the `SDO_POINT object type` via the `.x` attribute.

```
--generates test data; feel free to ignore:
with cte as (
select  sdo_geometry(2001, NULL, SDO_POINT_TYPE(123, 456, NULL), NULL, NULL) as shape 
from    dual)
    
select
    (shape).sdo_point.x as x,
    (shape).sdo_point.y as y
from
    cte

         X          Y
---------- ----------
       123        456
```

> [2.2.3 SDO_POINT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/spatial-datatypes-metadata.html#GUID-1BEDE913-87BA-4EBD-BFFB-09C95C93A04E)
>
> The SDO_POINT attribute is defined using the SDO_POINT_TYPE object
> type, which has the attributes X, Y, and Z, all of type NUMBER.

---

Important:

You can't just do this: `shape.sdo_point.x`, since Oracle thinks `shape` is a table alias.

You either need to create a table alias such as "a" and use it like this:  `a.shape.sdo_point.x`. Or wrap `shape` in brackets so that Oracle knows it's not a table alias: `(shape).sdo_point.x`.

Related:

- [Techniques for selecting an object's attribute](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4498503/techniques-for-selecting-an-objects-attribute#latest:%7E:text=surround%20the%20object%20name%20in%20braces)
- [Get object's attribute](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/get-st-geometry-object-s-attribute/m-p/1174306)

Answer (score 1):

This is my table and its contents; column `GEOM` is `SDO_GEOMETRY`.

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 GEOM                                               MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY

SQL> select id, geom from test where rownum = 1;

        ID GEOM(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_ORDINATES)
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1062937 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9176067, 46,2172763, NULL), NULL, NULL)

SQL>
```

Extracting `X` and `Y` coordinates is quite simple:

```
SQL> select a.x,
  2         a.y
  3  from test t cross join table(sdo_util.getvertices(t.geom)) a
  4  where t.id = 1062937;

         X          Y
---------- ----------
16,9176067 46,2172763

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks -- do you know why ocacle doesn't allow you to just directly query for t.geom.x ?

Comment: You're welcome. I have no idea; try to ask Oracle, they know.